# QlistWidget retains the previous index value

Tags: python, pyqt5

Why is the `self.selected_item` and `self.selected_index` not `None`?

```
class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()
        self.image_url = None
        self.selected_item = None
        self.selected_index = None
        self.selected_movie_title = None
        self.selected_episode_id = None
        self.selected_episode = None
        self.movies_episodes = []
        self.selected_movie_id = None
        self.selected_movie = None
        self.movie_downloader = None
        self.movie_fetcher = None
        self.movies = None
        self.query = None
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.query_input = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "query_input")
        self.search_btn = self.findChild(QPushButton, "search_btn")
        self.download_btn = self.findChild(QPushButton, "download_btn")
        self.movie_list_widget = self.findChild(QListWidget, "movie_list")
        self.episode_list_widget = self.findChild(QListWidget, "episode_list")
        self.movie_image = self.findChild(QLabel, "movie_image")

        self.search_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_movie_input)
        self.query_input.returnPressed.connect(self.get_movie_input)
        self.download_btn.clicked.connect(self.download_selected_episode)
        self.movie_list_widget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.get_movie_index)
        self.episode_list_widget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.get_selected_episode)

    def get_movie_input(self):
        self.movie_fetcher = MovieDetails()
        self.query = self.query_input.text()
        self.movies = self.movie_fetcher.fetch_object(self.query)
        self.display_movies()

        def display_movies(self):
        self.clear_movie_list()
        print("New Movies")
        for movie in self.movies:
            self.movie_list_widget.addItem(movie['title'])
        self.movie_list_widget.setCurrentRow(0)

    def clear_movie_list(self):
        print("CLEARING")
        self.movie_list_widget.clear()



    def get_movie_index(self):
        self.selected_movie = self.movies[self.movie_list_widget.currentRow()]
        print(self.selected_movie)
        self.selected_movie_id = self.selected_movie['id']
        title = self.selected_movie['title']
        self.image_url = self.selected_movie['image']
        self.display_episodes()
        self.set_image()
        self.clean_title(title)
```

when I trigger the `get_movie_input` method, the display movies should be triggered (removing all previous item in the widget before repopulating it). Then, when I select an item in the widget, it  assigns its index to the `self.selected_index`.

This is where bug happens.

When I search a new movie, it gives me an index error here `self.selected_movie = self.movies[self.selected_index]`

This is a sample run:

```
>> Movie: The Mummy 
>> Fetch all movies that has the word "The Mummy" ##assigns it to self.movies (let's say length of the list is 10)
>> QListWidget gets populated 
>> I click any item in the QListWidget. ##Let's say I clicked index 8. it displays the picture of index 8.

NEW QUERY
>> Movie: Star Wars
>> Fetch all movies that has the word "Star Wars" ##assigns it to self.movies (let's say length of the list is 3)
>> it returns an error here and not clearing the widget. the self.selected_index is still 8 rather than None
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "E:\Programming Projects\PythonProjects\movie_downloader\main.py", line 66, in get_movie_index
> > self.selected_movie = self.movies[self.movie_list_widget.currentRow()]
> > IndexError: list index out of range

Summary: I search a movie with an array length of 6. then click any index that is greater than my next query. For the next query, I seearch a movie with an array length of 1. The index from the previous query is trying to index the current array which causes the indexError.

[image: Here is the video of the length of an array for earch query and the index I am trying to access]

Comment: Why are you duplicating this state in your own class instead of just calling `self.movie_list_widget.currentItem()` each time you need it?  It seems like there are lots of ways that the duplicate index could get out of sync with the list and you'd need to hook up to more signals on the list widget to catch them all.  But it's easier to just not duplicate the data in the first place.

Comment: sorry, which state? (which part of the code)

Comment: `self.selected_index` and `self.selected_item`.  I don't think these should exist at all; `self.movie_list_widget` is the source of truth for this information, and querying it costs nothing.  Those attributes are just copies, which can go stale and lead to bugs (similar to what you're seeing, although in looking closely I'm not sure if that's exactly the problem in this specific case).  Rather than trying to make sure they never go stale, you should just not have unnecessary copies.

Comment: If you really wanted to have a `self.selected_index` for convenience, have a `@property` that pulls it directly from `self.movie_list_widget` on demand.

Comment: The other issue is that you're assuming the indexes between `self.movie_list_widget` and `self.movies` will always line up, which seems like a really dodgy assumption.  You should make `movies` a dictionary (keyed on `title` maybe, or some more unique identifier if one exists) so that you can always look up the movie based on information that's guaranteed to exist in the list widget.

Comment: "it returns an error here": *what* error? Please provide the full traceback. Also note that there's really no point in creating a `self.ui` object and then using `findChild` to create attributes for the window instance: `loadUi` already creates attributes for *both* the `ui` object *and* the target widget, so you *already* have all those references (`self.self.query_input` etc.). In fact, you could even avoid creating the `ui` object reference at all: just use `uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)` without assigning it to anything.

Comment: @Samwise I removed the some variables that are duplicating the data. but I still get the index out of range. I changed the code above.

Comment: @musicamante I added the traceback above. I removed the `self.ui` thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @mangoorange add the following at the very beginning of `get_movie_index`: `currentRow = self.movie_list_widget.currentRow()` `if currentRow < 0: return`, then you could use `self.selected_movie = self.movies[currentRow]` directly. I'm not completely sure, though, and we would probably need a valid [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I tried that code but still causes index error. I edited my post above by adding a summary and a gif on how I reproduce the error.

Comment: That's most certainly caused by a delay in the selection update. You should also temporarily disconnect from the `itemSelectionChanged` before clearing and reconnect again afterwards. In any case, the video is insufficient, your code is a bit confusing and is missing parts, so we cannot be completely sure until you provide a MRE as requested.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I disconnected the `itemSelectionChanged` and wait for the new data. Thanks for the help though!